# A problem on fixed point of a doubly differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $g : [0,1] -> \Bbb R$ be twice differentiable (i.e. both $g$ and $g'$ are differentiable functions) with $g''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. If $g(0) >0 $ and $g(1)=1$. Show that $g(d)=d$ for some point $d \in (0,1)$ if and only if $g'(1) > 1$. How to prove it ? Looks like need to use MVT, but where ?. Only a hint is enough.

Comment: Think of the picture: $g$ is convex as $g''>0$. If $g'(1)>1$, around $x=1$ the graph of $g$ is below the line $y=x$.

Comment: yes, from picture it is intuitively clear. But, how to use MVT ?

Comment: I am thinking of IVT: As $g$ is below $y=x$ around $1$ and is above $y=x$ around $0$, it must somewhere cut the line $y=x$ in $d\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x) = g(x) -x$.

If $\exists d\in (0,1)$ such that $f(d) = 0$, then, since $f(1) = 0, \exists z \in (d,1)$ such that $f'(z) = 0$.

Since $f''(x) = g''(x) > 0$ on $[0,1]$, what can you say about $z$? What do you conclude about $f'(1)$?